# How to add laravel validation for updates only once?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.3, rules

My function to update like this :

```
public function updateRating(UpdateRatingRequest $request) {
    $param = $request->only('id', 'rating');
    $id = $param['id'];
    $rating = $param['rating'];
    $review = Review::find($id);
    $review->rating = $rating;
    $review->save();
}
```

My validation rules like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class UpdateRatingRequest extends FormRequest {
    public function rules() {
        return [
            'id'=>'required',
            'rating'=>'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

I want to add validation server side laravel. If a particular id column, the rating column has been updated, it can not be updated again. So every id, its rating column can only be updated once

For example I have id = 8. if on the id = 8, the rating column has been updated. Then the rating column at id = 8 can not be updated again. So it can only be updated once

How can I do it?

**Update**

This is my way of checking id that has a null rating with mongodb :

```
$reviews = Review::where('_id',$param['id'])->whereNull('rating')->first();
```

The process is the same as laravel

Comment: Are there any other columns in that table that can be updated? If so, what is the value for the rating column before it's updated?

Comment: I think you just need to add a column flag for rating. Lets say the column called rating_updated and this column has something like a boolean value (true/false). It it's true, then the rating column is already updated. You can easily check it.

Comment: @Ross Wilson, Yes, it's updated_date column. Value for the rating column before updated is null

Comment: @wlisrausr, Whether it can not go through the column rating? Before updating the column rating is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said in the comments that the rating value is null beforehand you could use the [exists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-exists) validation rule:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'id'     => [
            'required',
            Rule::exists('reviews')->where(function ($query){
                $query->whereNull('rating');
            })
        ],
        'rating' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Please note you will have to include the `use` statement for the `Rule` facade in your `UpdateRatingRequest` class:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does not work. There exist message : `The selected id is invalid.`

Comment: I use mongodb and mysql. Reviews table use mongodb

Comment: @SuccessMan I've never used mongodb so there are a few unknowns on my end. Would you be able to edit your question to show how you would check if the rating value is null in mongodb?

Comment: I have updated my question. It seems it should use the model. Whether to use the model for validation?

Comment: @SuccessMan In that case if mongodb is your default db connection then you should just need to specify the column in the `exists()` column i.e. `exists('reviews', '_id')`. If it is not your default connection then will need to specify that as well i.e. `exists('mongodb.reviews', '_id')` (change mongodb to the name you have in your config file if it's different). If this doesn't work either let me know as there is something else you can do but involves a little bit more work.

Comment: @SuccessMan Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add extra column something like "isEditable" with default value 1

Then in rules -

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'id'=>'required',
        'rating'=> ['required', 'exists:isEditable,1']
    ];
}
```

When you update, change the value of isEditable to 0 and then validator won't allow to update again.

Comment: Whether it can not go through the column rating? Before updating the column rating is null. So I do not need to add extra column